# It is not possible to establish a connection with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a little weird inconvenience. 9 months ago I have a Windows VPS with SQL Server database, which I was always using from a WebHosting that was connected remotely to my server. Yesterday suddenly the VPS suffered a forced reboot surely by some applications that were running and consumed too much memory, today when I try to access my website I find that it is not possible to establish the connection with the server.
Another thing that may have been is that you change the password of the windows user. but I change it to the user of the database so that it does not use windows authentication.

The port is fine, the services are started TCP / IP is enabled, user and password is all OK, I can not find an answer to why it can not connect.

Will this forced reboot have damaged SQL Server or something like that?

Comment: Check in your windows vps, can be a simple firewall rule that got activated by the reboot, but without the log there it can be anything

Comment: Firewall is disabled.